# How to design a simple linear DC circuit in Ngspice?

Tags: software

I'm trying to implement a simple linear DC circuit in [ngspice](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/), but the program and manual are overwhelming. The circuit I'm trying to get started with is a voltage source (e.g. cell) connected to itself through a resistance.

Looking at the list of independent voltage sources (which I assume is what I need), I can't find a simple potential difference:

- Pulse
- Sinusoidal
- Exponential
- Piece-Wise Linear
- Single-Frequency FM
- Amplitude modulated source (AM)
- Transient noise source
- Random voltage source
- Arbitrary Phase Sources

Am I misunderstanding something? How to design the circuit?

Comment: Or: Where can I find a simple example to start working from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some simple example netlists in the \Tests folder.

A DC voltage source would be specified as:

V1 1 0 5

Where V1 is the name (could be V2, V3, etc) 1 is node 1, 0 is circuit ground and 5 is the voltage.

Here is a basic circuit to try, a voltage source connected to a 1 ohm resistor and stepped from 0 to 10V with current plotted for R1 (not tried it but it should be okay, let me know if not)

** Circuit Description **
V1 1 0 5
R1 1 0 1

*.option noacct
.dc V1 0 10 1

.plot i(R1)

.end

It's probably not the easiest SPICE to pick up, you might want to try [LTSpice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice).

Comment: Unfortunately, LTSpice doesn't seem to be available to Linux.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame as it's a great tool. Maybe you can run it in [Wine](http://www.brorson.com/gEDA/SPICE/x496.html)?

Comment: You can. I remember reading somewhere that the LTSpice developers purposely code things in a way to help ensure it runs within Wine properly. I wish I could cite where I found that.

Comment: @draeath - Is it not the link I posted above? (it's not to the Wine page, it's to a discussion of spice on linux and mentions the tweaking - I should have been more descriptive with the link name)

Comment: I did not read it.